# Is it possible to have a keyed dictionary stored on disk?

Tags: java

for example) would it be possible to be able to use the key of an item to access the item stored in a file out on disk (without searching through the whole file)?

I'm looking fora general example of how to do this (assuming it's possible), as I don't actually need to do this, it was just a question from an old exam.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  What do you have in mind?

Comment: sorry, I should have specified that I have nothing in mind. I was going through old final exams for one of my classes, when this question popped up, and I thought it was probably possible, but wasn't sure how I would go about. i'm just looking for how it would be done in general. I'll edit the question as well.

Comment: See [ISAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISAM) for the canonical example, about 50 years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed. There's something called disk-based hash tables. You generate keys that correspond with a physical location in disk.

The accepted answer in this [SO question tells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495161/fast-disk-based-hashtables) you a possible implementation.

**I would suggest though** that you use a **[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) dabatase**. Load the data into it and create an index.

When you use the indexed column for searches you don't search through the table. A fast hash-based or b-tree-based look up is done on the index ( which is sorted ). Then the index points to the row in the table directly. Probably SQLite uses a hash function for that also, like most RDBMS.

SQLite requires no database daemon running, just the SQLite binary or a library for your programming language of choice.

Comment: thanks a lot, this is pretty much what I needed. I'll be looking into disk-based hash tables

Comment: **Any** relational database provides you with a "keyed dictionary  stored on disk" when you create a table with an indexed primary key.

Comment: @DocBrown I guess OP's question is not RDBMS oriented, but how to implement a key->hash->disk_sector at low-level. Anyway, I recommended the SQLite option because it's the closed there is to not having a dedicated RDBMS, but then we would  not learn to do the hack himself.